Publish Real time Event Monitoring events to AWS
Tried using 'Event Relays' to send real time event monitoring events to AWS, while i was able to add Login LogOut events to the event channel i am not able to add other events like ApiEvent or ApexTriggerEvent.
How can i send events from the channel event/ApiEventStream for example to AWS EventBridge, appreciate any help


Some events are free, most aren't. Is your org licensed for it? https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring/event_monitoring_intro
